# Update cell values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing data row-wise, how can I update a data frame cell value in a loop (read a value, parse it, write it to another columnn)

I have tried the below code

```
data = pd.read_csv("MyNames.csv") 


data["title"] = ""
i = 0
for row in data.iterrows():

name = (HumanName(data.iat[i,1]))
print(name)
data.ix['title',i] = name["title"]
i = i + 1
data.to_csv('out.csv')
```

I would expect the following

```
name = "Mr John Smith"
              | Title
Mr John Smith | Mr
```

All help appreciated!

Edit: I realise that I might not need to iterate. If I could call the function for all rows in a column and dump the results into another column that would be easier - like a SQL update statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `HumanName` is a function or whatever that takes in a string and returns a dict you want. *not able to test this code from here, but you get the gist*

```
data['title'] = data['name'].apply(lambda name: HumanName(name)['title'])
```

**EDIT** I used `row[1]` because of your `data.iat[i,1]` that index might actually need to be 0 instead of 1 not sure

Comment: This worked really well, thank you so much for your helpful input

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.apply`

```
def name_parsing(name):
    "This function parses the name anyway you want"""
    return HumanName(name)['title']

# with .apply, the function will be applied to every item in the column
# the return will be a series. In this case, the series will be attributed to 'title' column
data['title'] = data['name'].apply(name_parsing)
```

Also, another option, as we're discussing bellow, is to persist an instance of `HumanName` in the dataframe, so if you need other information from it later you don't need to instantiate and parse the name again (string manipulation can be very slow on big dataframes).
If so, part of the solution would be to create a new column. After that you would get the ['title'] attribute from it:

```
# this line creates a HumanName instance column
data['HumanName'] = data['name'].apply(lambda x: HumanName(x))
# this lines gets the 'title' from the HumanName object and applies to a 'title' column
data['title'] = data['HumanName'].apply(lambda x: x['title'])
```

Comment: yes this is cleaner if you update the name_parsing function with the `HumanName` thing

Comment: I'm not really sure what object is `HumanName`. But if he already have the names (as string) in one column, he wouldn't need to instantiate another object.

Comment: `HumanName` is probably a class/function used to dissect name strings into various things like `title` `first_name` `middle_names` `last_name` people can have multiple titles etc. So if you do `HumanName(name)['title']` like in the question your anwer is perfect

Comment: I see. Thanks. But, in this case, maybe, wouldn't be better to have a column with the HumanName instance for that row? So if needed latter, it wouldn't be need to instantiate and parse the name again.

Comment: sure, that might be a valid tip, not sure this guy needs that flexibility though, might just be a quick table reformatting before saving again

Comment: Yes, maybe. But it may be useful to someone in the future... Just edited and put there as a second option.